# OpenSSH RSAAuthentication

Tags: ssh

I keep bumping into `RSAAuthentication yes` in OpenSSH configuration files in combination with `Protocol 2` option (It is in default configuration on Debian 8 and also in [Tecmint RHCSA post](http://www.tecmint.com/rhcsa-series-secure-ssh-set-hostname-enable-network-services-in-rhel-7/)).

The manual says:

> RSAAuthentication:
>
> Specifies whether pure RSA authentication is allowed.  The default is “yes”.
>                This option applies to **protocol version 1 only**.

Why would I specify something that affects exclusively protocol version 1, while allowing only protocol version 2 connections? Did I miss something? I thought that configuration files should be kept as simple as possible so there is less space to make mistake.

Comment: It's not in _my_ `sshd_config` on any system I manage. And that wouldn't be the first error someone has found on tecmint.com.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sorry, I currently don't have Debian default config on me, but it came to my mind while reading the linked post.

Comment: According to current debian (sid) git, the option is still there in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, as created by the postinstall script.: http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/tree/debian/openssh-server.postinst?id=2df85bb3e650f484fd3c95f2be89f4cc1bd0a341

Comment: Having perused the source, rsa_authentication really is only used in ssh1; if you compile with WITH_SSH1 undefined, the config options.rsa_authentication is never referenced.